# ввод строкового динамического массива с клавиатуры

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, поток-ввода

С клавиатуры вводим размер динамического строкового массива n, где n - натуральное число.

```
int n;
cin >> n;
char *massiv = new char[n];
```

Как теперь осуществить ввод данных в массив с клавиатуры вместе с пробелами? `gets_s(massiv)` или `cin.getline(massiv)`не компилит. И если я правильно понимаю, то обращение к этому массиву будет таким(допустим в цикле вывести введенный массив):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     cout << *(massiv + i);
}
```

И как чисто в теории вывести длину строки, если не весь массив будет заполнен, как например в случае со статическим массивом через `strlen(massiv)`

Answer (score 1):

А почитать документацию? :)

```
gets_s(massiv,n);

cin.getline(massiv,n);
```

Длина именно строки - как вы и написали, `strlen(massiv)`, вывести ее всю -

```
cout << massiv;
```

Comment: кажется вы  хотели написать   cout << massiv;

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Конечно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

если вы хотите использовать именно getline, то нужно знать, что  она прочтет строку от начала до конца.

```
int n;
cin >> n;    // оператор №1      
int k = cin.peek();
char* massiv = new char[n + k]; //  первые k элементов будут пустые
cin.getline(massiv, k);        // не лучшее решение
std::cout << massiv;
delete []massiv;
```

после оператора 1. состояние `cin` будет таков, что  `cin.peek()` имеет значение количество вводимых символов, поэтому нужно выделять память под массив настолько же больше (если вы хотите прочесть еще n символов, а не n символов вместе с ранее вводимыми).

а для вывода массива символов (и только), просто передавайте в поток сам указатеь

еще не совсем понимаю для чего нужно здесь выделять память с кучи, когда можно просто создать локально char `massiv[n + k]` и потом не заботиться об уничтожении

Comment: Я когда пытаюсь что то ввести у меня просто закрывается консоль. Может я библиотеку не подключил нужную?

Comment: вы введите цифру (вашу  n), а потом через пробел сразу то что хотите вводить. А если хотите по другому, то нужно менять программу

Comment: а почему вы написали что это не лучшее решение?

Comment: потому что с таким кодом первые k символы будут пустыми, потому что вы их  ввели уже  ( cin >> n;).  Если вы введете   100 , то  k == 3  и 3 первых элемента массива будут пустые

Comment: а что в памяти происходит, если одновременно друг за другом записать: gets_s(a, n); cin.getline(a, n);? Просто именно так работает как надо. То бишь я ввел свое n, сформировался массив размером n, затем пишу туда с клавиатуры и все норм. Законно ли это?)

Comment: думаю  Harry прав - вам лучше почитать документацию, а то так долго будем обсуждать... Нет, поможет не использовать getline() в таких случаях

Comment: почти любую задачу можно решить многими способами, я лишь дал вам информацию для размышлений, а дальше вы сами можете достичь решения вашей задачи, используя и свои знания и документацию  потоков ввода